# Can I use JBoss MQ on JBoss 5? If so, how?

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jbossmq

I have an application that was written on JBoss 3.2.5 and I am tasked with migrating it to JBoss 5.

I am unable to deploy the application because it relies on JBoss MQ, which I read has been replaced by JBoss Messaging.

Is there any way I can get the app to work on JBoss 5 without making any code changes?  Config changes are OK.

Comment: maybe you find partly an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610337/how-to-connect-jms-queues-from-jboss-4-and-5

Answer (score 4):

Actually JBoss Messaging is already being replaced by HornetQ.

In JBoss Application Sever 6.0, HornetQ will be the default messaging provider.

http://jboss.org/hornetq/

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way I can get the app to
>   work on JBoss 5 without making any
>   code changes? Config changes are OK.

Assuming that your code is written to the JMS API, then yes, you probably can. However, don't underestimate how different JBossMQ is from JBossMessaging, the configuration is completely different.

Depending on how hard your app pushes the JMS API, you may get behavioural differences, but the odds are you'll be fine, as long as you can reconfigure JBossMessages within JBoss5 appropriately.

Another option is to move to JBoss 4.2, which still has JBossMQ, but is miles ahead of JBoss 3.2. Much of the functionality that JBoss5 gives you can be done with JBoss 4 (e.g. it has partial JavaEE 5 support).

Answer (score 0):

JBossMQ will be replaced by JBoss Messaging in JBoss AS 5.0.
A good starting point to find out how to migrate would be [JBossMQ](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/jbossmq)