# How to connect JMS queues from JBOSS 4 and 5?

Tags: jboss, jms, messaging, jboss5.x, jbossmq

I have a server on which a Jboss 4.2.2 and a Jboss 5.1.0 runs. The problem is that a 3rd party is not able to upgrade its application to Jboss 5.1.0 in the near future, for us it is a simple matter. Unfortunately we need to send and receive some JMS messages from the third party app running on Jboss 4.2.2.

What is the easiest way to enable the transfer of JMS messages between JbossMQ and JbossMessaging?

Comment: Can you make changes to the app running on JBoss 4.x, or does the transfer have to happen without knowledge of the apps involved?

Comment: It depends, it is a different contractor, so it is mainly a question of time/money. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the solution for my problem. The JBOSS documentation has a chapter to migrate messages between JBOSS Messaging and JBOSS MQ: http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0.BETA/html/JBoss_Messaging_User_Guide/inst-mqmessagemigration.html

I have 2 topics myTopicSend and myTopicReceive on my JBOSS 4.2 and I have 2 topics myTopicSend5 and myTopicReceive5 on JBOSS 5.1.

I wanted to bridge all messages from myTopicSend to myTopicReceive5 and from myTopicSend5 to MyTopicReceive.

Somehow the configuration didn't work at all first, but after some time of experimenting I have now the following config:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.jndi.JMSProviderLoader"
       name="jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJBossMQProvider">
    <attribute name="ProviderName">RemoteXAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="ProviderAdapterClass">org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter</attribute>
    <attribute name="FactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="QueueFactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="TopicFactoryRef">XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    <attribute name="Properties">
        java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
        java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
        java.naming.provider.url=127.0.0.1:1099
    </attribute>
</mbean> 

<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.BridgeService"
       name="jboss.messaging:service=Bridge,name=LegayBridgeSend" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Bridge-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="SourceProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJBossMQProvider</depends>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="TargetProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=JMSProvider</depends>
    <attribute name="SourceDestinationLookup">/topic/myTopicSend</attribute>
    <attribute name="TargetDestinationLookup">/topic/myTopicReceive5</attribute>
    <attribute name="QualityOfServiceMode">0</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxBatchSize">1</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxBatchTime">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="FailureRetryInterval">5000</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxRetries">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="AddMessageIDInHeader">false</attribute>
</mbean>

<mbean code="org.jboss.jms.server.bridge.BridgeService"
       name="jboss.messaging:service=Bridge,name=LegayBridgeReceive" xmbean-dd="xmdesc/Bridge-xmbean.xml">
    <depends optional-attribute-name="SourceProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=JMSProvider</depends>
    <depends optional-attribute-name="TargetProviderLoader">jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=RemoteJBossMQProvider</depends>
    <attribute name="SourceDestinationLookup">/topic/myTopicSend5</attribute>
    <attribute name="TargetDestinationLookup">/topic/myTopicReceive</attribute>
    <attribute name="QualityOfServiceMode">0</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxBatchSize">1</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxBatchTime">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="FailureRetryInterval">5000</attribute>
    <attribute name="MaxRetries">-1</attribute>
    <attribute name="AddMessageIDInHeader">false</attribute>
</mbean>
```

A important thing I realized was, to tweak the **MaxBatchSize** and **MaxBatchTime** parameters, because I want to deliver the messages immediately to the target queue.

A description of these parameters may be found at http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5.0.0/html/JBoss_Messaging_1.4.6/index.html